# How to integrate "own" HTML in Typo3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3, fluid

I'm pretty new to TYPO3. Just learned how to write a template with Fluid and integrate the Bootstrap Framework. Somehow it worked.
https://enkomp.com

But I really haven't understand, how I integrate my own HTML (from the template) into TYPO3
Maybe I learn it with another easy example - a sticky footer

I have put this into my template boottpl.html

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

But after loading it in my templatefolder (where the other template is stored AND works) the sticky footer doesn't show up in the frontend.
Where do I need to place it?

Comment: Do you store your page fluid templates in your own extension? Or maybe under /fileadmin/ ? Could you post your TypoScript Template code?

Comment: Check there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855496/how-to-integrate-a-html-template-to-typo3/47864303#47864303

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the usage of typoscript and the folder-structure of fluid.
And the usage of the word "template". 
In TYPO3 multiple items are called template:

1. the records for typoscript
2. the prototypes for any kind of output (so HTML is preferred)
   a. (old) marker templates
   b. any fluid templates (`Layouts/`, `Partials/` and `Templates/`)
   c. the fluid templates in the `Templates/` folder

First you have to enhance the pathes to the fluid templates(b) which is defined in a typoscript template(a).

```
lib.fluidContent {  
   // use `lib.contentElement` for TYPO3 8
   templateRootPaths {
      200 = EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/FSC/Templates/
   }
   partialRootPaths {
      200 = EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/FSC/Partials/
   }
   layoutRootPaths {
      200 = EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/FSC/Layouts/
   }
}
```

now for each template file(b) your folders are scanned first for a matching file and so your templates(b) can override the default ones.

now you need to know the logic of template files(c):

Any call goes to a template file(c) located in the `Templates/` folder.
That file can start with a `<f:layout name="layoutname" />` tag.
If that tag is given the rendering starts at the layout template(b)  `Layouts/layoutname.html`.
In that file you can call sections (by default from your template file(c)) and partials.
So you render your output with smaller blocks, you can use multiple times.

In this way you also can replace just one single block (e.g. partial) without the need to copy all template files(b).

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: Thanks for answering, @Bernd.   I already have enhanced the path to the .../templates, .../partials/ and .../layouts/:    10 {
  file = fileadmin/private/templates/boottpl.html
  partialRootPath = fileadmin/private/partials
  layoutRootPath = fileadmin/private/layouts  }    My navbar and content-container is working this way. in the templates-file I have enhanced them to the typoscript-file with <f:sectio...n>tags - I tried the same way with the sticky footer, but nothing showed up - even not in the source code.

Comment: Sorry @Bernd, I posted it better in the answer above - haven't used Stackoverflow for a longer time and not familiar with formatting in comments 

Comment: no linebreaks in comments :( if you want to identify your used footer try to identify the chain of templates. For this I copy the templates to my own space (never change the original) and insert everywhere html comments which identify the file (and section), if needed also with an start and stopp for identifying the end of a template.

Comment: You need to use lib.contentElement instead of lib.fluidContent in case you are using TYPO3 8 or later, see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/8.7/Configuration/OverridingFluidTemplates/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering @Riccardo Here't the code I put inside my setup.ts (stored under .../fileadmin/...:

```
page = PAGE
page {
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
    file = fileadmin/private/templates/boottpl.html
    partialRootPath = fileadmin/private/partials
    layoutRootPath = fileadmin/private/layouts

    variables {


    mitte < styles.content.get
    mitte.select.where = colPos=0


    }

}

includeCSS.bootmin = fileadmin/private/frameworks/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
includeCSS.boot = fileadmin/private/frameworks/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css
includeCSS.startertemplate = fileadmin/private/styles/starter-template.css

includeJSFooter.jquery = fileadmin/private/frameworks/jquery-3.2.1.min.js
includeJSFooter.bootjs = fileadmin/private/frameworks/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
}
```

within my template .../boottpl.html I make the connection via section-tags:

```
<f:section name="content">        
    {mitte -> f:format.raw()}
</f:section>
```

Well it does work perfectly fine for the name="content" and name="navigation"...and I thought, that I've understood that process - but I couldn't manage it with the sticky footer